# TIMESTAMP column not interpreting correct value for ORC file in HDP3.1

Tags: hadoop, hive, orc, bigsql

As part of cluster migration we are copying ORC hdfs files from old cluster - IBM IOP 4.2 to HDP 3.1. Post migration we see TIMESTAMP column shows -1 hour in HDP 3.1. Similar question posted in - [TimeStamp issue in hive 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47133093/timestamp-issue-in-hive-1-1)

We cross checked TIME ZONE configuration for all the nodes in cluster - Linux OS and Hive and both set to EDT (local time zone).

Tried testing this scenario by reading the ORC file content using hive -orcfiledump -d  and we see the actual file has the correct timestamp value in the orc file. The column value is getting changed when even Hive is reading it and displaying the records.

ORC external table output on OLD cluster.

```
DATE_KEY    DTDATE
20100701    7/1/2010 12:00:00 AM
20100702    7/2/2010 12:00:00 AM
20100703    7/3/2010 12:00:00 AM
```

ORC external table output on new HDP 3.1 cluster. The DTDATE column shows -1 hour

```
DATE_KEY    DTDATE
20100701    6/30/2010 11:00:00 PM
20100702    7/1/2010 11:00:00 PM
20100703    7/2/2010 11:00:00 PM
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you format your question a little better?  Newlines are helpful to help people read, and code should be in `codeblocks`.  See our [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) guide!